# Multiple devices on one power supply

Tags: power-supply

I am planning to have 10 devices that each consume 4A @ 5V each.  I am very new to this but from what I understand I would in theory need 5V 40A power supply.

I was looking at [this power supply.](https://amzn.eu/d/3Yv9yFk) (MOGOULUA Switching Power Supply 300W 5V 60A)

Am right in my assumption?  What would the wiring look like?

Comment: You are correct. Current adds for paralleled devices. Voltage adds for series connected devices.

Comment: Depends on the distance between devices and supply. We can't possibly know what you need. But a single 60A supply is a hazard. Even if your wires need to carry only 4A to your device without much voltage drop (which you also did not specify), a short circuit can provide 60A which can melt your 4A rated wire. It does not sound very safe.

Comment: Hi cheers for the help. OK distance between power supply and devices will be small. As for the wires would it be wise to get 60a rated wire even though it would only ever have 4a at full load?

Answer (score 2):

> What would the wiring look like?

The wiring capable of 4A for the devices is probably not capable of 60A.
You need to make sure you engineer the power distribution with fuses.

Remember: fuses protect the wires, not the devices.